# Dynamic drop down menus using jQuery for Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hello everyone I need some help making a drop down menu that is reactive to classes contained in a set of options. What I want to do is have users select brochures (I'll call the *brochure menu*) and based on the classes contained in those options, a second drop down menu is populated based on the classes in the first.

For example selecting this option:

`<option id="parRight" class="eng kor esp">Special Ed. Parents Rights</option>`

Would create a second drop down I'll call the *language selection drop down menu* based on the classes above of "English" "Korean" and "Spanish" respectively and only those languages represented in the classes of that particular option.

So far I have been able to populate the list correctly only on the first try. My problem is that when I move on and select another brochure from the first menu my `.append` method is just adding to the first language selection drop down menu.

Here is the relevant code:

HTML

```
       <select id="docs">
            <option>- Choose a document to preview -</option>
            <option id="specEd" class="eng kor viet esp chin">Special Education Programs</option>
            <option id="parRight" class="eng kor esp">Special Ed. Parents Rights</option>
            <option id="cac" class="eng esp">CAC Brochure</option>
        </select>

        <div id="langs">
            <ul style="display:none;">
                <li>-Select a Language-</li>
                <li class="eng">English</li>
                <li class="esp">Español</li>
                <li class="kor">한국어</li>
                <li class="viet">Tiếng Việt</li>
                <li class="chin">中文</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
    var $select = $("<select></select>");
    $("#langs").append($select);


    function englishTest(lang) {
    return lang.hasClass("eng");
    }

    function spanishTest(lang) {
    return lang.hasClass("esp");
    }

    function koreanTest(lang) {
    return lang.hasClass("kor");
    }

    function chineseTest(lang) {
    return lang.hasClass("chin");
    }

    function vietnameseTest(lang) {
    return lang.hasClass("viet");
    }

$("#docs").change(function(){
    console.log("test");
    var $selection = $("#docs option:selected");


    if (englishTest($selection) === true) {
            console.log("english passing");
            $select.append("<option>English</option>");
    } 
    if (spanishTest($selection) === true) {
            console.log("spanish passing");
            $select.append("<option>Español</option>")
    }  
    if (koreanTest($selection) === true) {
            console.log("korean passing");
            $select.append("<option>한국어</option>")
    }  
    if (chineseTest($selection) === true) {
            console.log("chinese passing");
            $select.append("<option>中文</option>") 
    }  
    if (vietnameseTest($selection) === true) {
            console.log("vietnamese passing");
            $select.append("<option>Tiếng Việt</option>")
    }       
});
```

I am aware that this code is repetitive and I'm not a fan of that. I'd also appreciate some pointers on how to clean this code up and make it so I'm adhering to DRY *Don't Repeat Yourself* coding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my code when you click on the drop down another drop down is created from the classes form the original options. I made a map of classes to languages that will be used  to output the options in the new dropdown. I hope you understand. If you have any questions let me know.

```js
$(function(){
  var map = {
    "eng" : "English",
    "esp" : "Español",
    "kor" : "한국어",
    "viet" : "Tiếng Việt",
    "chin" : "中文"
  }
  $("#docs").on("change", function(){
    //explanation of .attr()
    // lets say your html looks like this === 
    //<option id="specEd" class="eng kor viet esp chin">Special Education Programs</option> 
    // .attr("class") will create a string of all the classes like : 'eng kor viet esp chin'

    var selected = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");

    //then you split the string by spaces to get an arr like ["eng", "kor", "viet", "esp", "chin"]

    var arr = selected.split(" ");

    console.log(arr) //["eng", "kor", "viet", "esp", "chin"]


    //Next, remove the old dropdown that was appended. If `.added` was not there it will remove nothing
    //Then after it is removed append the new dropdown
    //so, on every change event you're removing the old and appending the new.

    $(".added").remove()
    $("body").append("<select class='added'>")

    //since the string of classes are split into an array you can use the array method of [forEach][1]
    arr.forEach(function(e){
     //`e` is each element in `arr`
      $(".added").append("<option>"+map[e]+"</option>");

     // so map[eng] == "English" then it goes to map[kor] etc..
     // you should know how JavaScript objects work

    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="docs">
  <option>- Choose a document to preview -</option>
  <option id="specEd" class="eng kor viet esp chin">Special Education Programs</option>
  <option id="parRight" class="eng kor esp">Special Ed. Parents Rights</option>
  <option id="cac" class="eng esp">CAC Brochure</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks a lot. I have a few questions. regarding `var selected = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");` Is this saying the variable `$selected` is equal to the selected option? I don't know what `this` is a reference to. Is it the selected option? You then are getting the class attribute with `.attr("class")?

Comment: Really if you could just kind of walk me through it. I need help knowing exactly what is going on line by line. I'm new at this.

Comment: Yes. `selected` is set to the selected option of the `#docs`  drop down. The dropdown is the context (this). I also get the classes of the selected by doing `.attr()`. This gives you a list of the classes.  You can provide a context object as the second parameter to a jquery selector as explained in this article http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/jquery-tip-1-defining-a-context-when-using-selectors. BTW. This following would also work:  `var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("class");`.

Comment: I added some comments to the answer. hope it helps.

Comment: Now my final aim is to have all of these options link to a picture or preview of a PDF in a container off to the side. Could I still do that with this code?

Comment: yes, I believe you can do that. If you want to make click events on dynamically created elements you should use the second parameter for the `.on`  event.  look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Answer (score 2):

For the DRY coding, I would suggest replacing these functions

```
function englishTest(lang) {
    return lang.hasClass("eng");
}
```

With something like this

```
function testLanguage(selection, lang) {
    return selection.hasClass(lang);
}
```

And then calling it like

```
testLanguage($selection, "eng") === true
```

For your main question, you seem to be appending stuff always when the selection changes, but you never clear anything.

Comment: ooo thanks for the suggestion, I'll incorporate that into my code. Thanks for the tip. Yes you are correct, I am appending every time the selection changes but I don't know of a way to "clear" as you suggest.

Comment: Try $select = $("<select></select>");

Comment: At the top of my .js file $select does =  ("<select></select>")

Comment: I meant you should add it inside change function to clear it, not sure if that works, but the answer Jack gave seems to be better anyways. :)