# Drop down menu adding attributes to options created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hello everyone I'm trying to get my two drop down menus to do the following:

1) Display a preview of the brochure that matches the selected options
2) Have that preview be a link to a pdf

So far with the help of Stack Overflow users my jQuery code looks like this:

```
var $brochureSelect = $("#docs");
var brochure = $("#docs option:selected").text();
var language = $(".added option:selected").text();

$(function(){
 var map = {
"eng" : "English",
"esp" : "Español",
"kor" : "한국어",
"viet" : "Tiếng Việt",
"chin" : "中文"
}

$brochureSelect.on("change", function(){

var selected = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
var arr = selected.split(" ");
$(".added").remove()
$("#langs").append("<select class='added'>")

arr.forEach(function(e){

$(".added").append("<option>"+map[e]+"</option>");



    });
  });
});

$brochureSelect.on("change", function(){

if ($("#docs option:selected").text().match("^-")){
    $("#langSelectBox #langs").hide();
} else {
    $("#langSelectBox #langs").show();
}

});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="docSelectBox" class="clearfix">

        <h3>Select a Brochure</h3>
        <select id="docs">
            <option>- Choose a document to preview -</option>
            <option id="specEd" class="eng kor viet esp chin">Special Education Programs</option>
            <option id="parRight" class="eng kor esp">Special Ed. Parents Rights</option>
            <option id="cac" class="eng esp">CAC Brochure</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="langSelectBox" class="clearfix">
        <h3>Select a Language</h3>
        <div id="langs">

        </div>
    </div>
```

I've run into a few problems:

1) my `language` variable isn't working. In the javaScript console it shows up as a blank string *`""`* but calling `$(".added option:selected").text();` in the console returns a string of whatever is selected. I don't know how to remedy this other than calling the long hand every single time.

2) Since the drop down menu is being created dynamically I don't know how to set attributes like `href` or `src` every time a new option is selected because there is no existing code to pull attributes from. That leads me to understand that I need to make my function that creates the drop down menus in the first place more robust. Would I have to add more arrays that correspond to different `src` or `href` values?

Something like:

```
map2 = {
brochure1. : "/folder/pdf1/language1", // language 1 is the default
brochure2 : "/folder/pdf2/language1",
brochure3 : "/folder/pdf3/language1"

}

//once brochure is selected then you can further change the preview based on the language selection
map3 = {
language1 : "/folder/pdf1/language1",
language2 : "/folder/pdf1/language2",
language3 : "/folder/pdf1/language3",
..etc..
}
```

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514213/dynamic-drop-down-menus-using-jquery-for-website) to my previous question, sorry I don't know how to run the little code snippet yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `language` variable is set at the start of the code so at this point the element you want to get doesn't exist and the value of language is `""`, you need to set the variable value when you change the `<select>` value.

Hope this can help you, if not guide me and I can help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/j6xxdpge/

Comment: This helped out immensely! Thank you very much. Now link to my pdf files! That was a simple fix I'll keep that around for years to come.